# Как открыть Persistent store Core Data в Terminal?

Tags: ios, ios7, coredata, persistance

Пытаюсь посмотреть содержание персистентного хранилища (*persistent store*) моего приложения через терминал (*terminal*).

В терминале ввожу:

```
find ~ -name ‘LeagueManager.sqlite'
```

где *LeagueManager* - название моего приложения

далее ввожу:

```
sqlite3 LeagueManager.sqlite
```

далее получаю путь к персистентному хранилищу:

> /Users/Aleksandr/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ABF32E90-AED7-4240-8458-75725577D185/data/Containers/Data/Application/467ADE4A-3E7B-4B36-BA75-221E18426CE3/Documents/LeagueManager.sqlite

далее терминал выдает строку:

> find: /Users/Aleksandr/Library/Saved Application State/com.adobe.flashplayer.installmanager.savedState: Permission denied

где в конце сказано: *Permission denied* - Доступ запрещен.

далее выдает:

```
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-07-17 17:46:21
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

Потом я ввожу команду показать схему базы данных

```
sqlite> .schema
```

и ничего не происходит.

Как разрешить доступ к базе данных?

Comment: Пробовали тоже самое с префиксом sudo?

Comment: @iFreeman, sudo вместо find?

Comment: перед командой открытия

Comment: @iFreeman, в хранилище вошел, а дальше ни какой реакции на команды .schema и .tables

Comment: @iFreeman вот terminal:  sudo find ~ -name 'LeagueManager.sqlite'
Password:
/Users/Aleksandr/LeagueManager.sqlite
/Users/Aleksandr/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ABF32E90-AED7-4240-8458-75725577D185/data/Containers/Data/Application/6C4F259B-61AC-4849-9570-8662B8D5F243/Documents/LeagueManager.sqlite
sqlite3 LeagueManager.sqlite
Mac-mini-Aleksandr:~ Aleksandr$ sqlite3 LeagueManager.sqlite
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-07-17 17:46:21
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .schema
sqlite> .tables
sqlite>

Comment: Открывать персистентное хранилище через терминал не смог, но нашел другой способ: использую sqlitebrowser для просмотра базы данных.